# Pass an array value for a radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form where a user selects one value from several of previously submitted values. I have used radio buttons so the user can only select one answer. But the problem here is that the original answers can have several values and can be in an array, so how do i pass an array as the value of the radio button??

What i am doing now is joining the array in the value of the radio button, and then splitting it and storing it when i receive it. 
So, in the view

```
<% answers.each do |answer|    
   <%= radio_button_tag "best_answer", answer.is_a?(Array) ? answer.join('|') : answer, :required => true %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller,

```
best_answer = params[:best_answer].split("|")
params[:best_answer] = best_answer.length > 1 ? best_answer : best_answer[0]
```

Can we pass the whole array from the single radio button itself or is there another better way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Is `Answer` an `ActiveRecord` object? If than just use `answer.id` as the value for the radio tags. If not, it's possible to change it to an `ActiveRecord`? ;)

Comment: I'm using mongoid and answer itself is not an mongoid object, but is a field of an object so if i pass the id, i would have to retrieve all of these objects from DB and get their values for the answer field. I guess current method of joining the array would be easier.

Comment: Ok and how about serializing (maybe to `YAML`) and maybe encoding the whole thing (with `Base64`)? Do you know what I mean, or should I post another answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to set the array as radio button's value? Just use a single value for that radio button that represents a set of values.